# Render slot as v-html

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

## Goal

How to implement a component that renders an html string (eg fetched from a CMS) passed as a slot like this :

```html
// app.vue
<script setup>
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent.vue"
const htmlStr = `not bold <b>bold</b>`
</script>

<template>
  <MyComponent>{{htmlStr}}</MyComponent>
</template>
```

#### Explanation

To render an html string (eg fetch from a CMS) we can use `v-html` :

```html
// app.vue
<script setup>
const htmlStr = `not bold <b>bold</b>`
</script>

<template>
  <p v-html="htmlStr"></p>
</template>
```

#### Failed attempts

I have tried with no success :

```html
// component.vue
<script>
import { h } from "vue";

export default {
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    return () =>
      h("p", {
        innerHTML: slots.default(),
      });
  },
};
</script>
```

Renders

> `[object Object]`

[Link to playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNpVUcluwyAQ/ZURJ1tK4O4SS1UvPTSn9sghcUJqR2YRjLvI4t87eGldLgyzvPfmMbJH7/nHoFnFZLyEziNEjYOvle2MdwHh+P3kKLLaItyCM6AYF5tknlZM2YuzEaFF079igAOcrENoXH8F2dT5lqKpT8pKMfMQAz1QG9+fUdMLQG5g63FcsFKSWz7qlOJ3jO3YrHNvzp7fo7O0yZjB1FKIilUwZXJuEltR0CL6WAkRb5e8wT1yF94FRTwMFjujuY5m3wT3GXUg4LwiQFI2EWUW89+1P79GaCGtTk10D3lT/TVVr/p2HnrqymiT04UPzscdzcXeYYRUrmoDlYOFooTDZE8+baGYV4za1wxAZ60Oz2/Hl2qG4AtJUe7WplSSCLookSja/AFLP7T9r+U=)

#### Workaround with props

As a workaround, we can of course use props but it's verbose.

```html
// app.vue
<template>
  <MyComponent :value="htmlStr">{{htmlStr}}</MyComponent>
</template>
```

```html
// component.vue
<template>
  <p v-html="value"></p>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps } from 'vue'
  
defineProps(['value'])
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`slots.default()` returns an array of your passed slot elements, try to map that  content and render it :

```js
h("p", {
   innerHTML: slots.default().map(el=>el.children).join(''),
  });
```

[Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9kT1PwzAQhv/KyUsTqXX2kEZCLAwwweihTeKSVP7S2SlIkf875ySlFUh4se/Dj+99PbFH5/hllKxklW9xcAG8DKOrhRm0sxjgyWoHJ7QaBONFilK/YMK01vgAfdDqLSDs4WBsgMaqDqqmTntVNPVBmKpYyMSkIEjt1DFIigCqxKunaYXEWM0vUK0qfhrZli2z7PTR8bO3hqad0nWxFrxgJcyZlJvHK+nQh+B8WRT+1KaZz55b/CjoxHE0YdCSS693DdpPL5HAgm3vGAUlLxJ3KE0nUeJ/zF+tf7gJG4WJJOXq4M3xm9cT9BCvZs8yHpJn8muudvJ0HBV1Jdr8S5lD6/yW7nllg4eYL8VFBVILGshy2M9mp9VngjnSeXUrrcEYic/vry/lguHrQ1nOyfBMqn0tFW/7QXUkMOdnO5hss8lXs0hZTmPSRolIp7v/ZvEbiFPOSA==)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass html to a component in a slot by doing `<template #default><div v-html="htmlStr"></div></template>`:

```
// app.vue
<script setup>
import Comp from "./Comp.vue"
const htmlStr = `not bold <b>bold</b>`
</script>

<template>
  <Comp>
    <template #default>
      <div v-html="htmlStr"></div>
    </template>
  </Comp>
</template>
```

```
//Comp.vue
<template>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

[**Vue SFC Playground**](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9Ub1OwzAQfhXLrCUZulVpJEAdYABEGT00Ta5timNb9jlUqvru3LmkNBIw+Xzfj787H+Wdc1kfQc5kEWrfOhQBMLpSmbZz1qN4sJ0TG287oWSW8435SipTWxNQ7LDTS/RiLlbGolhb3YhiXfJZ5OtypUyRn53Jky4IndMVAt2EKNgvVVQPiLhpYFNFzQIGCGraXvS3/NRcye8XlSyLnIBBno+dU1Qqr/pyIof8PO+YH7RFMkzHSKUM6TDQtJt2m+2DNSQ+skbJmuxaDf7FYUvbUHImEsJYpbX9fEo99BEmQ7/eQf3xS38fDtxT8tVDAN/Tji8YVn4LeIYXy2c4UH0BO9tETex/wDcIVkfOeKbdR9NQ7CteSvuYvrw12/ewOCCYMAzFQZl5SnwlaYO8yb9G/4k7zaZJp8xJnr4AzgDNNg==)